# Electron - what are the risks of disableWebSecurity in WebView?

Tags: javascript, security, webview, xss, electron

I'm loading a remote resource in a webview, but I want to inject some local content such as images (using preload script) into it. I guess the only way is to use the file protocol, but it won't work without disableWebSecurity set to true. Would that make my application vulnerable?

Edit: I managed to do what I wanted without disabling security by using a custom protocol, for some reason it is allowed. https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/protocol.md